# AG-Grid drag and drop cells

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Currently I have row and column drag and drop working, but I also need the individual cells to be movable, and I'm wondering if it's supported by the `ag-grid` library and if not, what would be the best approach to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: `ag-grid` has Custom Drag Component .Maybe that is what you are looking for

Comment: @BitchLasagna, thank you I will have a look.

Comment: Custom Drag Component is what I'm going to use, https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/drag-and-drop/#custom-drag-component thanks